# Производительность P/Invoke против Managed C++

Tags: c#, .net

Есть нативная библиотека. Её функции нужно вызывать из управляемого `C# .NET` кода. Что будет работать быстрее, `P/Invoke` или обертка на `Managed C++`?

Comment: Если вы не вызываете нативную функцию в цикле десятки тысяч раз в секунду, думаю, никто и не заметит разницы.

Comment: @VladD, ну там не одна функция будет, и вызываться эти функции будут как раз десятки тысяч раз) Поэтому и спросил.

Comment: Тогда у вас что-то не так с архитектурой проекта. Вызовы между границами модулей должны быть редкими. Попробуйте реорганизовать нативную библиотеку так, чтобы вызывать её пореже, пусть она получает задания пачками и накапливает результаты.

Comment: @VladD, понятно, тогда для этого нужна обертка из Managed C++, которая содержит в себе объединяющий все функции из неуправляемой библиотеки метод, из Managed C++ же не должно быть задержек.

Comment: Иначе у вас будут дикие расходы на маршаллирование данных и переключение между управляемым и неуправляемым контекстами (хоть с P/Invoke, хоть с Managed C++).

Comment: Не-не, расходы будут во многом те же, в MC++ переключение управляемого и неуправляемого контекстов и маршалирование данных из нативного представления в управляемое тоже дорогое (только маршалирование вы будете делать вручную). Я бы посоветовал пересмотреть архитектуру. Пять минут исправления архитектуры заменяют два месяца болезненных низкоуровневых оптимизаций.

Comment: @VladD, нет доступа к исходникам нативной библиотеки, так бы сделал в ней. Тогда нужно делать нативную функцию на С или С++ в еще одной дополнительной библиотеке, и дергать ее через P/Invoke. Про Managed C++ - забыть. Спасибо.

Comment: Смотрите. Вы можете делать и так, и так. Но вы должны уменьшить количество вызовов из управляемого кода в неуправляемый. Можно, например, на том же Managed С++ сделать полностью нативную обёртку, которая будет вызывать библиотеку, собирать результаты, отдавать в управляемый код. Или чисто нативный модуль, который будет делать то же самое, и вызывать его через P/Invoke. результаты должны быть практически одинаковыми, делайте, как считаете правильнее/удобнее/лучше.

Comment: @VladD, добавили бы в ответ последний коммент, а то у других может возникнуть похожий вопрос.

Comment: Добавил как ответ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы можете делать и так, и так. Для улучшения производительности нужно *уменьшить количество вызовов из управляемого кода в неуправляемый* (и обратно).

Можно, например, на том же Managed С++ сделать полностью нативную обёртку, которая будет вызывать библиотеку, собирать результаты, отдавать в управляемый код. Или чисто нативный модуль, который будет делать то же самое, и вызывать его через P/Invoke.

Результаты должны быть практически одинаковыми, делайте, как считаете правильнее/удобнее/лучше.